# Wordpress Illegal string offset

Tags: php, wordpress, input

I'm using the following code to determine if a checkbox has been ticked and then display some text if it has/hasn't as a test.

When its checked, it works fine and the text displays.

When its unchecked I get the message below on the input box line with a comment in my code below.

> Illegal string offset 'chec_checkbox_field_0'

```
<?php

    function webdev_init() {
    ?>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <h2>WedDev Overlay Plugin Options</h2>
        <form action='options.php' method='post'>
        <h2>Checking</h2>

        <?php
        settings_fields( 'my_option' );
        do_settings_sections( 'checking' );
        submit_button();
        ?>

        </form>
    <?php
    }

    function chec_settings_init() {

        register_setting( 'my_option', 'chec_settings' );

        add_settings_section(
            'chec_checking_section',
            __( 'Your section description', 'wp' ),
            'chec_settings_section_callback',
            'checking'
        );

        add_settings_field(
            'chec_checkbox_field_0',
            __( 'Settings field description', 'wp' ),
            'chec_checkbox_field_0_render',
            'checking',
            'chec_checking_section'
        );
    }

    function chec_settings_section_callback() {

        echo __( 'This section description', 'wp' );

    }

    function chec_checkbox_field_0_render() {

        $options = get_option( 'chec_settings' );
    ?>

    //Error message on line bellow
    <input type='checkbox' name='chec_settings[chec_checkbox_field_0]' value='1' <?php if ( 1 == $options['chec_checkbox_field_0'] ) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />

    <?php
    }

 $options = get_option( 'chec_settings' );
if ( is_array( $options ) && $options['chec_checkbox_field_0'] == '1' ) {
    echo 'Checked';
} else {
    echo 'Unchecked';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that the given index is not present in the array `$options`.

It seems that you are fetching the value of $options from HTTP request. As your input is a checkbox it is not present in the request when unchecked.

Because, in case of html form a checkbox is simply absent from the request after submission if it is unchecked.

It means checkbox has only two states either set or not set. So, you should check for `isset()` to identify if the checkbox is checked or not.

```
if ( isset( $options['chec_checkbox_field_0'] ) && $options['chec_checkbox_field_0'] == '1' ) {
    echo 'Checked';
} else {
    echo 'Unchecked';
}
```

Comment: Okay. where would i check for isset()?

Comment: I added. Please check.

Comment: Have you replaced it at both the places?

Comment: what do you mean both places?

Comment: You have checked the condition at two places in the given code. One below your comment and another at the bottom of the code

Comment: Oh, forgot that part. Thank You!

Comment: No problem at all :)